# JavaFX background color using three colors

Tags: java, javafx

[image]

How I can create this type of background(white, black, white) in javafx?

I tried `-fx-background-color: white, black, white;` but is not what I want.

Comment: try using RadialGradient, official documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/paint/RadialGradient.html

Comment: Is the region the circle? Or does it include the blue background?

Comment: @Slaw Yes, the region is circle. Blue background was just to make visible big white circle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to come up with a CSS styling resulting in this:
[Inner Circles example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eB0id.png)

```
.circle-background{
    -fx-background-color: black, white; /* 2nd inner color, 3rd inner color*/
    -fx-background-insets: 10,60; /*2nd inner ring, 3rd inner ring */
    -fx-background-radius: 50%;
    -fx-border-width: 10;   /* outer ring width */
    -fx-border-color: white;/* outer ring color */
    -fx-border-radius: 50%;
}
```